# Calling startActivity(new Intent(context, activityA.class) creates another instance of activityA?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Say I have activityA (launcher activity), and from here I start activityB. At this point activityA is on the activity stack. Now from activityB I call `startActivity(new Intent(context, activityA.class)`.
My question is: it creates another instance of activityA or recreates activityA?

Comment: It creates a new instance of A. I see in your comments to other answers that you want that to happen. However, this will probably get you in trouble, as then A starts B again it will create a new instance of B and then you return to A and create a new instance of A and so on. Soon you will have dozens of instances of A and B. That sounds like a really bad architecture.

Comment: No, thats no what I want. I don't want to create another instance of activityA. Simply I want to finish activityB and recreate activityA when the user clicks a button in activityB.

Comment: Added an answer for you based on this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish B and recreate an instance of A (what you said you wanted to do in the comments), do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will finish B and also finish the existing instance of A, and then create a new instance of A.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did. It is working but, I don't know if I can trust on that flag to always recreate activityA and in all versions of android. I'm a little paranoic XD.

Comment: I was thinking in using that flag and adding some extra check in `onPause()` and `onResume()` of activityA. But I don't know if I would be sacrificing performance in vain.

Comment: No, you are good. It works correctly on all Android versions. That's a documented, standard, behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

it creates a new instance of activityA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid, that the activityA is launched twice, you can use this flag:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

[Link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: Nice, but I need to recreate activityA.

Comment: do you want to recreate activity to refresh data or get something?@Mike087

Comment: To reset all data in activityA and to get new sharedpreferences values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use already existing instance of  activity and also want to refresh some data in that activity,you no need to recreate that activity ,instead move that refresh data logic into onStart() because onStart() will invoked first not onCreate() when you use existing instance.

first call finish() method to close activity B and avoid new activityA instance creation.

```
          @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            refreshData();
     
    }

//If you can not call refreshData() in onStart(),try below code

Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //this method will clear ActivityA instance from stack.

then create new instance of Activity A from B using intent.
```

Comment: I need to recreate activityA, or finish old instance of activityA and create another instance of activityA. My refresh data logic can't be in onStart().

Comment: Did you try ,after startActivity B, finish() to close A?@Mikeo87

Comment: No, because I don't want to always finish activityA. It depends on what the user do in activityB.